# In Python, how do I refer to an identifier by its absolute fully-qualified name?

Tags: python, namespaces

I have a project with a directory structure that looks like:

```
/foo/baz/__init__.py
/bar/foo.py
/bar/splat.py
```

Problem is, `/bar/splat.py` refers to the `foo.baz` module.  This fails with the error `No module named baz` because it's trying to search for this module within `/bar/foo.py`.  I don't want Python to search the `bar` module, I want to tell it to search the root `foo` module for `baz`.  How do I do that?  In Ruby you'd just prefix the identifier with `::` (In this case, `::Foo::Baz`), is there a Python equivalent to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.5 and 2.6,

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

should change Python's `import` behavior to do what you want (if the very root, /, is on `sys.path` of course;-).  This becomes the normal Python behavior in 2.7 (not released yet, but an early alpha is already tagged, if you're curious).

Comment: Incidentally, this is an App Engine project, so it's Python 2.5.2.

Comment: @Bob, always glad to help -- btw, mentioning the Python release(s) of interest in the question's a good idea, in general, since some environments (e.g. GAE) constrain you to 2.5, in most cases people can use 2.6, others are trying 3.1, etc, and the best answers may often depend on what version(s) you care about!-)